# What software is this in my menubar?

Tags: macos, applications

[image]

Right beside the Alfred icon, there's a small up and down arrow indicating bandwidth upload and download speeds.

I remember downloading and installing something for this, and now I can't remember the name of it. I'm trying to enter the settings for it and also add in the RAM tickers.

Any ideas on what software causes the up/down icons next to the black hat icon?

Comment: Just FYI on Mac it's called the Menu Bar :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That program is MenuMeters, available at http://www.ragingmenace.com/

Comment: I'll be. It looks just like iStat Menus. I need a new prescription. :-)